# stripping tags from excerpt in Wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, strip, strip-tags

I am using this snippet

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' title='<?php echo strip_tags(the_excerpt()); ?>
```

with which I am intending to remove all `ellipses`, `<p>` tags and other `shortcodes` and `links`, but that does not work at all.

If I hover the anchor, I am still getting to see the `<p>` wrapped in the excerpt, as well as other tags and the url links. What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do to get it working?

Comment: You are missing an `echo` with `the_permalink()`

Comment: The `permalink` works without the `echo`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you need is `get_the_excerpt():`

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' title='<?php echo strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>'>
```

However, it probably won't strip out ellipses (…) since they're HTML entities, not tags.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the_excerpt() outputs the excerpt right away. You want get_the_excerpt() which returns it as a string you can maninpute (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt).

You can also use wp_filter_nohtml_kses() (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses)

Something like:

```
$title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses(get_the_excerpt());
```

Comment: <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>' title='<?php echo wp_filter_nothml_kses( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>'>

Comment: The second solution worked for me, the accepted answer not.